# Backspace key does not work for material ui TextField with NumberFormat

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to use react-number-format (NumberFormat) to format a numeric value 
within the material ui TextField. In this is example 
I can type new number characters, but I cannot remove any 
number characters using the backspace key.
I also cannot use the arrow or the delete keys.
The only way I can remove any number character is to 
select those characters with the mouse and press 
the space bar.

While not mine, the following code sandbox replicates what I am getting:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-iny12?file=/demo.tsx

```
function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
    const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <NumberFormat
            {...other}
            customInput={TextField}
            getInputRef={inputRef}
            onValueChange={values => {

                onChange({
                    target: {
                        value: values.value,
                    },
                });
            }}
        />
    );
}

<TextField
    margin="dense"
    fullWidth={true}
    value={value}
    onChange={handleNumberChanged}
    variant="outlined"
    autoComplete="off"
    type="number"
    InputProps={{
        inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
    }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a console warning telling you the problem:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `type` of value `number` supplied to `NumberFormat`, expected one of ["text","tel","password"].
>       in NumberFormat (at demo.tsx:14)

If you remove the invalid `type="number"` from the `TextField` then it seems to work fine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ovx7i

Comment: Is there a workaround to have type="number" which works but also make backspace work there?